# Trying to close portable browser via selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser, python-webbrowser

**I am trying to close portable browser via selenium**

I passed `--remote-debugging-port=9222` because if I do not pass it then the program is stuck in object creation of `webdriver.Chrome()`. It will open the portable browser but not load the URL.

But after the URL is open I want to close the browser but `driver.quit()` it is not working for me. I have tried some other methods for close the browser but they do not work as well.

I want to close the specific instance of the browser which is opened by this program not other opened instances of the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:/Portable/GoogleChromePortable/GoogleChromePortable.exe'
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Person 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path='C:/Portabl/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

I am using:

```
selenium 3.141.0, windows 10, python 3.8.0, portable chrome version 93.0.4577.63 (32-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your this statement

> I passed --remote-debugging-port=9222 because if I do not pass it then
> the program is stuck in object creation of webdriver.Chrome()

is not correct. `--remote-debugging-port=9222` looks like a port number where your application is deployed and you have used chrome option to send them to `browser object`.

```
driver.quit()
```

this typically should have worked, what is the error when it did not work ?

also, for closing a single instance you could do

```
driver.close()
```

see if that helps.